# ggplot - heat color palette

Tags: r, ggplot2

i want a color scale like in the picture:

[image]

So from top to buttom we have:

a very bright yellow (white-ish), orange, red, black, blue, light blue to very bright blue (white-ish)

I want a value of 0 always to be displayed as "black". The smallest (negative) value should be that "extreme bright blue". The biggest value (postive) should be the "extreme bright yelllow".

Please note that the min and max are not equally distant from the origin 0.

Thats where i am:

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(xDim = c(0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2), yDim = c(2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0), high = c(0, -1, 6, -3, 8, 5, -2, 7, 5))

ggplot(df, aes(xDim, yDim)) +
    geom_raster(aes(fill = high)) +
    scale_fill_gradient2(low = "blue", mid = "black", high = "red", midpoint = 0)
```

Comment: Use `scale_fill_gradientn` instead, with appropriate breaks and colors.

Comment: true that. is there a way to automate that? i have many DF with many different values.

Comment: You could use `quantile` to set the breaks. Also consider the `viridis` color palettes: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/viridis/vignettes/intro-to-viridis.html  Some of the palettes seem similar to what you want, and would be a drop into `ggplot` with `scale_fill_viridis(option="plasma")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scale_fill_gradientn` is most suited for this. You just need to get an appropriate vector of colors, then come up with a good range of values for those colors.

In your case, we could choose as colors:

```
col <- c('yellow', 'orange', 'red', 'black', 'blue', 'skyblue', 'white')
```

and as values:

```
val <- c(seq(min(df$high), 0, length.out = 4), seq(0, max(df$high), length.out = 4)[-1])
```

We need to use `rescale` according to the docs, so we do:

```
p <- ggplot(df, aes(xDim, yDim)) +
  geom_raster(aes(fill = high)) +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours = col, values = scales::rescale(val))

cowplot::ggdraw() + cowplot::draw_plot(cowplot::get_legend(p))
```

[image]

Comment: thanks i think i can use that and tweak it a little bit! nice